# PostgreSQL 9.6. Issue dropping index

Tags: postgresql, ddl

In a legacy PostgreSQL DB I tried to drop an existing index issuing the command:

```
DROP INDEX testing.idx_testing_data_model_output_data_id;
```

and see the error:

```
ERROR:  index "<index name>" does not exist
```

But I can see the index using the `\d <table name>` command:

```
leg=# \d testing.data_model
                                           Table "testing.data_model"
     Column     |            Type             |                                 Modifiers
----------------+-----------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 id             | bigint                      | not null default nextval('testing.data_model_id_seq'::regclass) 
 input_data     | text                        | 
 output_data_id | bigint                      | 
Indexes:
    "pk_testing_data_model" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "idx_testing_data_model_output_data_id" btree (output_data_id)
```

Ok, when I try to create the index I receive the following error:

```
ERROR:  relation "<index name>" already exists
```

It seems that somehow the index creation or index dropping was not successfully complete. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Here it is but trying to format more nicely

Comment: So what is the **exact** command you use to drop the index?

Comment: i used "drop index <schema_name>.<index_name as is from \d cmd>"

Comment: it was "testing.idx_testing_data_model_output_data_id"

Comment: So, i can't delete this index and can't create( What should i do?

Comment: If you did include the quotes like that, that's the problem. It must be `"testing"."idx_testing_data_model_output_data_id"` - each element of the name must be quoted separately

Comment: Thank u for suggestion, but i can drop other indexes w/o any quotes at all: smth. like "DROP INDEX schema.idx_factor_log_id;"

Comment: Thank you. I edited the way you suggested

Comment: Your table is stored in the schema `testing`, however you use the schema name `exp` in your drop statement. The index is always stored in the same  schema as the table

Comment: excuses. it was obfuscating. i modified the name in drop index cmd.

Comment: do you know how i can delete this index?

Comment: You can list indexes for table with their full name (that you can safely copy&paste into DROP) using this query: `SELECT c.oid::regclass FROM pg_class AS c JOIN pg_index AS i ON i.indexrelid = c.oid WHERE indrelid = 'testing.data_model'::regclass::oid`. Check if it has the same name as the one you try to drop (including double quotes).

Comment: a_horse_with_no_name, your suggestion about quotes around schema name and around index name helped me to resolve the issue. Make a separate post and i'll mark it as the answer. Thanks for the assist!)

Answer (score 9):

```
SET search_path = <schema_name>;
```

Setting search_path worked for me.